# Can I explicitly close a RestSharp connection?

Tags: c#, rest, soap, restsharp

I have a class that looks like this :

```
private static RestClient fpSclient = new RestClient("https://myurl.com/api") { Timeout = -1 };

public static List<string> APISearch(string req){
      var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
      request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic ..."
      request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
      request.AddHeader("Cookie", "JSESSIONID=...");
      var raw = $"<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ ..."
      request.AddParameter("application/xml", raw, ParameterType.RequestBody);
      var response = fpSclient.Execute(request);
}
```

A team member reached out today saying that my account had tons of connections open. This script runs every five minutes 24/7.

Is there no way to do something like :

```
fpSclient.Close();
//or
fpSclient.Dispose();
```

Comment: Inside your "//Several more headers added that work fine" there is a "keep alive" on?

Comment: @LeandroBardelli no there isn't I've edited my post to show all of my headers

Comment: I would write the request with "using" to ensure dispose after connection.